# Using an array, loading sounds into app for iTunes

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, itunes

I'm trying to file share multiple files with iTunes file share.

Here is the current code.

Delegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // file sharing trying
    {
        NSString *fileName = @"Test.mp3";
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *documentDBFolderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentDBFolderPath])
        {
            NSString *resourceDBFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourceDBFolderPath toPath:documentDBFolderPath error:&error];
        }
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

At the moment only 1 sound file gets shared.

Thanks

Comment: This code copies a single file from your bundle to the documents directory. Where is the code you are having a problem with? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to share more than 1 file. I have 5 mp3's that i want to share, but the code only shares 1 mp3. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put each of your filenames into an NSArray:

```
NSArray filesToShare = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Test1.mp3",@"Test2.mp3",@"Test3.mp3",@"Test4.mp3",@"Test5.mp3",nil];

for (NSString *filename in filesToShare)
{
    ... Your existing code goes here, 
}
```

Obviously you would move the parts that are identical each time to before the for loop (getting the paths, creating the file manager etc).

Comment: Hi, I've tried the code. However the items are not showing in iTunes now. The app shows but no items.

Answer (score 0):

Though not an answer to your question, adding songs to iTunes is generally done by [Scripting Bridge](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/UsingScriptingBridge/UsingScriptingBridge.html).

You should generate the iTunes.h header file by running this in Terminal:

```
sdef /Applications/iTunes.app | sdp -fh --basename "iTunes"
```

And then add something like this in your code:

```
NSString *file = @"/path/to/test.mp3";
iTunesApplication *iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier: @"com.apple.iTunes"];
iTunesTrack *track = [iTunes add: [NSArray arrayWithObject: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: file]] to: nil];
```